# How to infer type of interface property by passing its property as argument?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

here is my example:

```
export const getField = <T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(fieldName: K) => {
  const record = injectRecord<T>(); // sideEffect

  return { field: record[fieldName] };
};

// in real life here will be different objects
const injectRecord = <T>() => ({ number: 123, bool: true, string: 'asd' } as T); 

// typeof field = string | number | boolean
const { field } = getField<{ number: number; string: string; bool: boolean }>('bool');
```

I want to get the correct type by passing the interface key, for the example above field should be exactly Boolean

Comment: TypeScript doesn't support *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) ; you either specify both `T` and `K`, or the compiler infers both `T` and `K`.  You can't specify `T` and have the compiler infer `K`.  Workarounds involve splitting into a curried function as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOLVEN). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, thank u very much! You made it absolutely clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a curried function:

```js
const injectRecord = <T>(): T => ({ n: 123, s: 'abc', b: true } as T);

const getField = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>() => <K extends keyof T>(key: K): { field: T[K] } => {
    const record = injectRecord<T>();
    return { field: record[key] };
}

const { field } = getField<{ n: number; s: string; b: boolean }>()('b');
//       ^? const field: boolean
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=4.9.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAVgU2FASqkAnAJjAXhgB4AVAPgAoBKALhlMPJkoG8Yx6BGAJgGYANDAj0A5AEMARsFFDJ9KNgCuyGAF8Y4iA2oBuALAAoI6EiwA5sigAxOMgA2+ImRjIAHlGRhc2zKDzE0NgI5kJKYADWYCAA7mDkVNRMJADSrh5ePjARyACeIABmDFQ5ufQpdDDsBXaO9KQA2ikAuurJrEYwXTCm0DDYWHiE8EioGIO4ZIkGht39VkrYYFUwNQ649AP+uA2lrWozakYm4H3VtfgaRJY2F8TsnBxKALaSyNi6wvRBIZ-yMJIQCB7MhxMs1IlKKJJKI9EYAPTwubdAB6AH4jEA). Prompted by [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349#issuecomment-1080754195)